# python 2 code: if python 3 then sys.exit()

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

I have a large piece of Python 2 only code. It want to check for Python 3 at the beginning, and exit if python3 is used. So I tried:

```
import sys

if sys.version_info >= (3,0):
    print("Sorry, requires Python 2.x, not Python 3.x")
    sys.exit(1)

print "Here comes a lot of pure Python 2.x stuff ..."
### a lot of python2 code, not just print statements follows
```

However, the exit does not happen. The output is:

```
$ python3 testing.py 
  File "testing.py", line 8
        print "Here comes a lot of pure Python 2.x stuff ..."
                                                        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So, it looks like python checks the *whole* code before executing anything, and hence the error.

Is there a nice way for python2 code to check for python3 being used, and if so print something friendly and then exit?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Python will byte-compile your source file before starting to execute it.  The whole file must at least *parse* correctly, otherwise you will get a `SyntaxError`.

The easiest solution for your problem is to write a small wrapper that parses as both, Python 2.x and 3.x.  Example:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info >= (3, 0):
    sys.stdout.write("Sorry, requires Python 2.x, not Python 3.x\n")
    sys.exit(1)

import the_real_thing
if __name__ == "__main__":
    the_real_thing.main()
```

The statement `import the_real_thing` will only be executed *after* the `if` statement, so the code in this module is not required to parse as Python 3.x code.

Comment: You could also use an `if __name__ == "foo"` block, which works like an `if __name__ == "__main__"` but executes when `foo` is imported

Comment: Wouldn't it be considered more *Pythonic* to use EAFP and just put the import of the_real_thing inside a `try` block?

Comment: @martineau: I wouldn't do this in the case at hand.  The `import` might very well succeed, and other errors could happen in `main()`.  You don't want to enclose `the_real_thing.main()
` in try/except.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: I don't really get your comment, but I added `if __name__ == "__main__":` for completeness.

Comment: @SvenMarnach: `if __name__ == "__main__"` is the first block that's executed when foo.py is run. `if __name__ == "foo"` is the first block that's executed from foo.py, when foo.py is imported in bar.py.

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: Those blocks are only executed first if they are at the beginning of the file.  Probably I'm dull, but I *really* don't get it!

Comment: @SvenMarnach: you could add such block at the beginning of the file. Then, it wouldn't matter if the rest was py3.x compliant/parseable. My communication protocols are probably deprecated which is why I am not able to get my point across to you. You likely don't know this, but I've been looking up to you for a few years now. So please don't say "I'm dull"

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: Before Python starts executing a module, the whole file is byte-compiled.  This includes parsing the whole file.  Adding `if __name__ == "foo"` doesn't change anything about this.